# How To Make Drop Down Menu Hover Less 'Twitchy'

Tags: jquery, menu, hover, delay

I have a fairly pedestrian multi-level drop down menu here: http://suntowersystems.com

If you hover of 'Products' you'll see the multi-levels. Unfortunately, it's too 'twitchy'. ie. if you hover on the first sub-menu (SAFE Extensions) to expand that level, it then becomes almost impossible to then slide down to the next menu (Remote Office). You have to sort of slide -around- it to get to the other selections.

Is there some way to 'slow' or 'delay' the responsiveness so that the hover event doesn't 'fire' for a few extra milliseconds?

TIA,

---JC

Comment: I'm lazy. Please point at the relevant code.

Comment: Paste some code here. In the future your link might be DOWN and no help from any of the answers. (Think about future generations and welcome to SO.)

Comment: You need a setTimeout that will make your drop down a bit lazy and slower.

Comment: I get errors on the page and the sub-menu is already expanded once I hover the Products (ie8) and in compatibility mode I see nothing on the page AT ALL.

Comment: You can also consider animating the height of the container to match changing contents.  Non-trivial, but a more rewarding (and less twitchy) UI.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's call hover intent http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: Hey THANKS! This was a great learning experience. I am not sure it's the final solution, but it helped me define the problem. For any other fellow travellers... The real issue is that, if you have multiple expandable levels, they open/close so fast it's tough to see what's going on. hoverIntent slows everything down enough to realise the -real- usability issue. Which is: if you have multiple expandable items, you just need to leave all levels already open, -expanded- so that the menu stays at the same height. It kinda doesn't need SetTimeOut at all---just keep track of which levels are open.

Answer (score 0):

yes its called hoverIntent http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: Can I post the same answer too?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes, its called hoverIntent

Comment: @ Rodolfo... Yes, it's called http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: No, its called hoverIntent and just for reference i was posting it at the same time i just seem to have taken 1 more minute to perform a gloogle search

Comment: Hi thanks! hoverIntent seems like worth a try!

Sorry if anyone got errors. I'm working on like 20 things at a time on the site. I see an error in another plug that makes IE fail.

Comment: ALSO: 
If I wanted to attempt to use SetTimeout() can someone give me an idea -where- to put that? The menu is just a typical Wordpress UL and the dropdown is just:

 $("li#menu-item-1195 ul > li ul li").hover(
   function(){$(this).addClass("hover"); 
  $(this).children('ul').show(300) },
  
   function(){$(this).removeClass("hover");  
  $(this).children('ul').hide()}
 );

...where would I put the SetTimeout to 'delay' the hover event when the mouse moves over the target?